# Sending data from kafka docker container to elastic search docker container

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, apache-kafka

I am using spotify/kafka docker image & official elasticsearch docker images but I am unable to send any logs from kafka to elasticsearch.Kiindly guide. I am using kafka version 2.11-0.8..2.1 with elasticsearch 2.3.2

Comment: What failed? Was there a error message in the logs? The only thing that it could be without more information is that the container cant connect to the other one. For that you have to use links or overlay networks

Comment: I am using weave network as an overlay network.While running kafka I am giving a weave dns as "kafka.weave.local" so that any other service trying to access kafka can use that dns for accessing it.But I don`t have much experience with elasticsearch so I am unable to find the correct way to push data from kafka to elasticsearch. 
I came across several solutions like elasticsearch river plugin, kafka connect,stream2es but due to lack of experience in elasticsearch i am couldn't get a clear visibility of which option is efficient & reliable for docker environment.

Comment: I tried https://qbox.io/blog/kafka-and-elasticsearch-a-perfect-match-1 but could get  it working after running run_standalone.sh I was getting error after sometime in kafka container too.